# How can I ignore time or time zones on a date object when comparing it in a .where?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need a document to be returned on a `.where("date" == selectedDate)` for the same day it was selected by the user independently of timezones.

Currently I store this date attribute with the hour, minute and seconds set to 0 (startOfDay using `date-fns`). If I'm on the same timezone, all docs created with a particular `date` will match the `selectedDate` just fine. However, if I change the timezone, the "startOfDay" of the `date` create in a timezone will not match the `selectedDate` of another timezone.

How can I ignore time so I can match the `date` with `selectedDate`?

I've done `.where(date >= startOfSelectedDate).where(date <= endOfSelectedDate)` and it does return documents from all timezones if the same day (apparently), but it ignores some cases where the dates (after converted) would be different in different timezones, like a doc created in New Zealand seen in Brazil, for example, Brazil would be a day behind.

For this particular doc all I care is that the date is consistent across timezones - think of it as an agenda - if I write a note on March 19th, doesn't matter where in the world I am, it will always be written on page March 19th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp and Date objects don't have any notion of timezone, and neither does Firestore.  The [JS API docs for Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) read:

> A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone or calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

The SDK will not help you in any way deal with the issues surrounding timezone.  That's something you will need to handle in your own code.  Your code will have to detect the timezone to work with, then do some date math to convert everything to UTC, which is what Firestore (and pretty much all systems) use to represent a point in time.  Once you've converted your timezone-dependent times into UTC, you can use those to query.